# Python: Convert Dictionary with Tuple as key to a sparse matric using Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary where the key is a tuple of length 2, and the value is a number, like this:

{('Alf', '2012.xlsx'): 600}

I want to create a sparse matrix, where Alf is the name of a row, 2012.xlsx is the name of a column, and 600 is the value where those two meet. And I want that to happen for all the other values in my dictionary. There may be keys like ('Alf', '2013.xlsx') and ('Elf','2012.xlsx')

The dictionary can be of any size, so I was thinking after creating it, I would loop through it and create a dataframe cell by cell, but I'm struggling to do that.

Here's the code I've written to create this dictionary (ing_dict). I'm open to approaching this problem in a different (better) way.

```
for filename in os.listdir(inv_folder):
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    if ext == '.xlsx':
        if filename==inv_file:
            continue
        recipe_files.append(filename)
    
#loop through list of files, load each workbook, and send it to the inventory function      
for file in recipe_files: 
    file_counter += 1
    file_path = inv_folder+'\\'+file
    wb = load_workbook(file_path,data_only=True)
    sheet=wb.active
    inventory(sheet,file,file_counter)

def inventory(sheet,file,file_counter):
    print('\n',file)   
    for row in sheet.iter_rows(2,18,1,3):
        if row[0].value:
            ing_dict[(row[0].value,file)]=row[2].value
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should do what you want. I added inline comments to explain how I transform your data.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# The expected input data
data = {('Alf', '2012.xlsx'): 600, ('Elf', '2012.xlsx'): 400, ('Alf', '2013.xlsx'): 200, ('Tim', '2014.xlsx'): 150}

row_to_pos = {}  # maps a row name to an actual position
data_new = {}    # We need to reformat the data structure

# loop through the data
for key, value in data.items():
    row=key[0] # e.g., 'Alf'
    column=key[1] # e.g., '2012.xlsx'
    
    #  if a row name is new, we add it to our mapper
    if row not in row_to_pos:
        row_to_pos[row] = len(row_to_pos)
        
    # if a column name is new, we add a new entry in `data_new`
    if column not in data_new:
        data_new[column] = [[],[]]
        
    # store our data, key=column_name, value=a list of two lists
    data_new[column][0].append(row_to_pos[key[0]]) # store the position
    data_new[column][1].append(value) # store the actual value

# we did not know in the first place how many unique row names we have so we have to loop once more
for key, value in data_new.items():
    tmp = np.zeros(len(row_to_pos))
    tmp[value[0]] = value[1] # value[0] are the positions, value[1] the corresponding values
    data_new[key] = tmp

# create our dataframe
data_new['Name'] = list(row_to_pos.keys())
df = pd.DataFrame(data_new)
df = df.set_index(['Name'])
print(df)
```

This results in the following output:

```
      2012.xlsx  2013.xlsx  2014.xlsx
Name
Alf       600.0      200.0        0.0
Elf       400.0        0.0        0.0
Tim         0.0        0.0      150.0
```

Comment: Great, thank you!

I am struggling to follow this. It seems I likely didn't go about this process in the best way. Any recommendations on a different way to store the data I am getting from my excel file in this format?

Comment: I think it is difficult to optimize it because (as far as I can tell) we don't know in advance how many different names (e.g. "Alf") we will have. Hence, I think you can keep your code as it is, i.e., `ing_dict` which you get from your `inventory` method can be directly feed into my code above (`ing_dict` is called `data` in my code). My code seems quiet long but it is actually efficient in respect of the runtime complexity. So there is no need to worry. If my answer solved your problem, please accept it. Please look here for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers